# setSpacing in VerticalPanel vs. HorizontalPanel

Tags: google-apps-script

Horizontal spacing using `.setSpacing()` within `HorizontalPanel`s seems to work as expected when the App is included into a GoogleSite as App Gadget (Firefox), but I can't figure out how to control vertical spacing within widgets in `VerticalPanel`s:

```
  var panel_A = uiApp.createHorizontalPanel();
  panel_A.add(t1).add(t2).setSpacing(30); // works as expected, horiz. space betw. t1 & t2
  var panel_B = uiApp.createHorizontalPanel();
  panel_B.add(t3).setSpacing(30); // shifts t3 widget to the right
  var panel   = uiApp.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(panel_A).add(panel_B).setSpacing(10); // has no apparent effect
```

The docs do distinguish between a vertical `setSpacing()` and a horizontal `setSpacing()` but I'm clearly missing something. Thanks.

EDIT

Simplifying things further and combining various `setHeight` and `setSpacing` settings won't change the spacing between `t1,t2,t3` (5 x 3 table charts). Ive tried enclosing the `vpanel` within an `hpanel` (I've been able to control the `hpanel`'s width) but that didn't alter the vertical spacing between the three tables.

```
  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
  var vpanel = uiApp.createVerticalPanel().setHeight('50%');
  vpanel.add(t1).add(t2).add(t3);

  uiApp.add(vpanel);
  return uiApp;
```

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1647)? There's a decent explanation in there.

Comment: Yes, and I've tried various combinations of `setHeight` values with and without `setSpacing`. I've removed the horizontal panel altogether, and even within a single vertical panel, the three tables keep displaying the same way, no change in vertical spacing between tables.